# DMS behavior when changing selection rules and resuming task

Tags: aws-dms

With a full load and ongoing replication task, if you stop it, add a few selection rules to bring in more tables, remove some selection rules to exclude some already synced tables, then resume the task, how's it behave?  I tried removing tables from a failing job to figure out what happened but it wouldn't change the list of tables till I did a restart not a resume.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on at which phase you are stopping and modifying the task. If you stop the task during full load phase and modify the selection rule, resume will not work. As resume is not applicable during full load phase, you need a restart. If the task is stopped at cdc phase, modified to exclude the tables, then resume works and migrates data only for the tables in the included list.

Comment: In my testing resume worked but left the stranded table there, honestly I think dms is like a black box with a crazy cat inside that likes to hiss at random and you never know why, getting really sick of it